# R : Fuzzy name match for variable size

Tags: r, fuzzy-comparison

I have been working on matching the source set with master set of customer names while this can be achieved by using `-adist` in R but now I have been using 2 million of source set with 500k of master set, here we cant use the `adist` as it does not support long vectors, so I have chunked the data to small set now i have 70 k of source set and 20k of master set while here the data sets size varies and hence can not use `adist` as it doesn't support variable size of sets and I have tried with various other ways to achieve the same by `amatch`, `pmatch`, `agrep` but not much help, I have referred these 
 sites which I found but couldn't find solution.

- [Super fuzzy name checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290350/super-fuzzy-name-checking)
- [Faster R code for fuzzy name matching using agrep() for multiple patterns...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026460/faster-r-code-for-fuzzy-name-matching-using-agrep-for-multiple-patterns)
- [Record linking and fuzzy name matching in big datasets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310363/record-linking-and-fuzzy-name-matching-in-big-datasets-in-r)
- [R: String Fuzzy Matching using jarowinkler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29102155/r-string-fuzzy-matching-using-jarowinkler)
- [Fuzzy string matching in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175380/fuzzy-string-matching-in-r)

I have tried with `levenshteinDist`, `levenshteinSim` and `jarowinkler` but have problem implementing for huge dataframe , can i find solution for my data frame similar to [this solution using jarowinkler for different size of sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175380/fuzzy-string-matching-in-r)

Comment: Couple of comments for you: (1) `adist()` definitely *does* support unequal vector sizes, e.g. `adist(letters[1:2],letters[1:3])`; it returns a matrix for the result. Unless I misunderstood your point? And (2) I don't think lack of support for long vectors is the only constraint here; running `adist()` on two vectors of length 2e6 and 5e5 respectively would result in a *crazily* huge matrix, completely impossible for most computer systems to handle. For example, I just tried it on my system, and got the following error message: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7450.6 Gb".

Comment: Can you explain how you're planning on using the resulting distance numbers? For example, are you looking for the first match for each customer name that has a distance number below a certain upper threshold? If that's your logic, you should be able to get chunking to work with `adist()`, provided you keep the chunks reasonably small and immediately discard all but the best match for each customer name.

Comment: @bgoldst that is the similar error i got , that's why i had to chunk the data into small sets and now it works , after long time but not efficient. it doesn not produce result expected.